# Why this loop of searching in lnked list runs infinitely?

Tags: list, loops, infinite

I am a beginner C programmer. I cant understand why the program goes into an infinite loop and print "The key element is not found". It may be a trivial error. Please help me.This program is to delete a node of a linked list

The program code is avalible here.
https://repl.it/@sandipanman/Linkeddel

Comment: Please put relevant code into your question.

Comment: Sorry,I have updated the link now.

Comment: There are many issues with your program.  But I'm guessing the one you speak about is most likely because you're not clearing your input buffer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7898516/6020034 for details. 
Also keep DRY (don't repeat yourself) in mind.  You should probably make a function for getting the user input.

Comment: The code is still not in the question.